# How to print a message in the console between the times form 9.00 AM to 16.30 PM in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to print a message in the console every hour between the times from 9.00 AM to 16.30 PM using flutter.

Comment: I want to understand please.
Do you want to post a message every hour from 9am to 4pm, or just the difference in hours ?

Comment: What kind of app? What console? Should that app be running at that time?

Comment: post a message every hour from 9am to 4pm @SteveNosse

Answer (score 0):

You can setup a cron job using this [package](https://pub.dev/packages/cron). Here is an example of cron expression that will perform an action every hour from 9am to 4pm: `0 9-16 * * *`.